# fsockopen socket connection is established in constructor but is null in other methods

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm writing a php IMAP API. The constructor connects to them Gmail server and stores the socket in a variable. When I use the same socket connection in another method, the connection is null. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
class Imap{

    const RESPONSE_SIZE = 4096;
    const LOCAL_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const CRLF = "\r\n";

    //------------RESPONSE CODES---------//
    const OK = "OK";
    const BAD = "BAD";
    const NO = "NO";

    //----------------FLAGS--------------//
    const FLAG_ANSWERED = "\\Answered";
    const FLAG_FLAGGED = "\\Flagged";
    const FLAG_DRAFT = "\\Draft";
    const FLAG_DELETED = "\\Deleted";
    const FLAG_SEEN = "\\Seen";

    //------------- PRIVATE VARS ------------//
    private $_connection = NULL;
    private $_number = 0;
    private $_instruction_num;

    private $_connected = false;
    private $_authenticated = false;

    //------------- PUBLIC VARS ------------//

    public $error = array();

    function __construct($imap_server, $imap_port)
    {
        $this->connect($imap_server,$imap_port);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        if($this->_connected)
            $this->logout();
    }

    private function connect($imap_server, $imap_port)
    {
        if($this->_connected == false)
        {
            if($imap_server == NULL)    $imap_server = self::LOCAL_HOST;
            if($imap_port == NULL)      $imap_port = 993;

            $this->_connection = fsockopen($imap_server,$imap_port);

            if(empty($this->_connection))
            {
                throw new Exception('Connection to server could not be established');
            }
            else $this->_connected = true;      

        }

        return $this->_connected;
    }

    function login($username, $password)
    {
        echo 'connection: '.$this->_connected;
        if(!$this->_authenticated)
        {
            $instruction = $this->get_instruction_num();
            fputs($this->_connection,"$instruction LOGIN $username $password".self::CRLF);
            $response = $this->get_response($instruction);

            switch ($response['code']) {
                case self::OK:
                    $this->_authenticated = true;
                    break;

                case self::NO:
                    $this->_authenticated = false;
                    $this->error = array('error'=>'Invalid username or password.');
                    break;

                case self::BAD:
                default: 
                    $this->_authenticated = false;
                    $this->error = array('error'=>$response['response']);
                break;
            }
        }

        return $this->_authenticated;
    }

private function get_response($aInstructionNumber)
    {

        $end_of_response = false;

        if(empty($this->_connection))
            die('DEAD');//connection is null here.

        while (!$end_of_response)
        {
            $line = fgets($this->_connection,self::RESPONSE_SIZE);
            $response .= $line.'<br/>';

            if(preg_match("/$aInstructionNumber (OK|NO|BAD)/", $response,$responseCode))
                $end_of_response = true;
        }

        return array('code' => $responseCode[1],
            'response'=>$response);
    }
```

Used in Mailer.php

```
class Mailer
{
    const imap_server = "ssl://imap.gmail.com";
    const imap_port = 993;
    const smtp_server = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    const smtp_port = 465;

    private $imap = NULL;
    private $smtp = NULL;
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";

    private $logged_in = false;

    function __construct()
    {
        try{
            $this->imap = new Imap(self::imap_server,self::imap_port);
            $this->smtp = new Smtp(self::smtp_server,self::smtp_port);
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    function login($username,$password)
    {
        if($username != NULL) $this->username = $username;
        if($password != NULL) $this->password = $password;

        //$this->imap = new Imap(self::imap_server,self::imap_port);
        if(!$this->imap->login($this->username,$this->password))
        {
            $result = array('success'=>0,'message'=>$this->imap->error());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->logged_in = true;
            $result = array('success'=>1,'message'=>'Login successful');
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

The code in the logging in page:

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['mailer']))
{
    try{
        $mailer = new Mailer();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    $_SESSION['mailer'] = serialize($mailer);
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    //ENCRYPT
    $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    $password = htmlentities($_POST['password']);
    $s_mailer = $_SESSION['mailer'];
    $mailer = unserialize($s_mailer);

    $_login = $mailer->login($username,$password);
    if($_login['success']!=1)
    {
        $feedback = $_login['message'];
    }else
        header('Location: inbox.php');      

}
```

Comment: `is_resource($this->connection)`returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the Mailer class in SESSION and expecting that the connection keeps alive across several requests. Note that this will not work.

Instead you could store the [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)d Mailer object in the SESSION and implement [__sleep and __wakeup](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php) to establish the connection again on [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: thanks! I've updated my code, but the unserialize method gives an error `unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`. Sorry, I'm new to PHP

Comment: `Sorry, I'm new to PHP` -> No problem. Clear your session or start a new one before testing this.

Comment: Ok, now it accusses $mailer of being a non-object after unserialisation: `Call to a member function login() on a non-object `.

Comment: Do I have to add __sleep and __wakeup methods to the imap class as well?

Comment: As Mailer will connect as soon as the constructor is called, I see currently no reason for that. But I'm unsure. You should test it without Imap::__sleep, ... first

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot fix your whole application from remote. Especially as I don't have a GMail account. If you do it the *right way*, __sleep and __wakeup is the way to go